# How To check if entered letters are in a list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

How can I check if the letters of a word that the user entered are all in a list?
This doesn't seem to work:

```
letters = ["a","b","c","d"]
inpt = str(raw_input())
if list(inpt) in letters:
    print "letters are in list"
else:
    print "letters are not in list"
```

Comment: Should *all* letters be in the input, or only *some* letters?

Comment: as the result of `raw_input()` is string you dont need `str` then , whats the type of input ?

Comment: [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) letters or [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) letters?

Comment: `if inpt in letters:` will work.

Comment: all letters should be in the list

Comment: @ρss: `inpt = 'abcd'`, then `inpt in letters` will **not** work, not in any Python version. That's because there is no `'abcd'` element in the list.

Comment: Yes your are right. it only works for a single letter but not for a word. I misunderstood  the question. thanks Martijn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example like this?

```
letters = set(["a","b","c","d"])
inpt = raw_input()
if set(inpt).issubset(letters):
    print "letters are in list"
else:
    print "letters are not in list"
```

cf. [Python - verifying if one list is a subset of the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/python-verifying-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-the-other)

Comment: You already converted the `letters` list into a set, so you don't need to do that again inside the `.issubset()` call. Similarly, the `str(raw_input())` is redundant since `raw_input()` returns a string (but I guess you just copied that from the OP).

Comment: @Lara: this is the *inverse* of what you said it should do. Use `set(inpt) <= set(letters)` rather than `set(letters) <= set(inpt)`. You wanted all letters in input to be in `letters`, not all `letters` to be in `inpt`. Or did you use *letters* to mean the characters in `inpt`? In which case you used very confusing wording.

Comment: @zormit: your code is rather redundant. You can use `set(inpt).issubset(letters)` here, no need for the extra `list()` and `set()` calls.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  I wanted to _check_ whether the letters from "inpt" are in the list "letters"

Comment: @Lara: yes, that much is now clear, but [your earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237231/how-to-check-if-entered-letters-are-in-a-list/28237348?noredirect=1#comment44835802_28237231) was not clear and used confusing terminology.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yeah, thx, you're right. I removed the redundancy.

Answer (score 4):

Use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset); either test for an intersection or for a subset:

```
if set(inpt) & set(letters):
    # *some* letters are in inpt
```

or

```
if set(letters) <= set(inpt):
    # *all* letters are in inpt
```

or if you wanted all characters in `inpt` to be in `letters` (so only `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` can be used, use the inverse:

```
if set(inpt) <= set(letters):
    # *all* of inpt is in letters
```

Demo:

```
>>> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> inpt = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'
>>> set(letters) & set(inpt)
{'d', 'c', 'a', 'b'}
>>> set(letters) <= set(inpt)
True
>>> inpt = 'no letters in use!'
>>> set(letters) & set(inpt)
set()
>>> set(letters) <= set(inpt)
False
>>> inpt = 'abbacac'
>>> set(inpt) <= set(letters)
True
```

where an empty `set()` is considered false when used in an `if` statement, a non-empty `set()` is considered true.

Comment: doesn't work. maybe because inpt is a string and letters is a list

Comment: @Lara: define *doesn't work*. What did you enter at the input prompt? `set(letters)` creates a set of the letters, `set(inpt)` does the same for a string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It looks like Lara wants `set(inpt) <= set(letters)`, not the other way around.

Comment: @PM2Ring: right, which is exactly the opposite from what [was stated by the OP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28237231/how-to-check-if-entered-letters-are-in-a-list/28237261?noredirect=1#comment44835802_28237231). Or at best they used very imprecise terminology (with *letters* referring to the characters in `inpt`).

Comment: Perhaps. This grouping: _How can I check if (the letters of a word that the user entered) are all in a list?_ seems pretty natural to me (I'm a native English speaker). And the _in a list_ seems most likely to refer to the constant list.

Comment: @PM2Ring: sure, on re-reading I can see how it was meant to be read; but reusing `letters` plus an overuse of type conversions didn't make it obvious on first reading.