# How to check if all items in a sub-list are in a list? Python

Tags: python, list

my question is pretty much as above:

if you have 2 lists as below, how can you check if all items in the first list are in the second list.
eg

```
list_one=[1,2,3]
list_two=[1,2,3,4]
```

my current attempt is just "if all list_one in list_two:"

but this condition never seems to be filled and so nothing further takes place. Any help would be appreciated thanks :)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/python-verifying-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-the-other

Answer (score 9):

The `all()` function is used to check if all the condition are satisfied .We are getting elements from list_1 and checking if that is available in list_2 if all are available then we print "yes"

```
list_one=[1,2,3] 
list_two=[1,2,3,4]
if all(a in list_two for a in list_one):
    print "yes"
```

Comment: You can explicitly exit a loop with `break` on finding the stop condition, or use a `while` loop whose predicate includes the stop condition.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `all` with a generator expression, this will allow short-circuiting upon finding the first element that doesn't occur in your second list.

```
>>> list_one=[1,2,3]
>>> list_two=[1,2,3,4]
>>> all(i in list_two for i in list_one)
True
```

Answer (score 3):

I simply create a difference of sets and check is length.

```
assert len(set([1,2,3]) - set([1,2,3,4])) == 0
```

Note that in boolean context empty sets (like any other containers) are falsy, so you can simply so something like:

```
if set(seq1) - set(seq2):
    do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> l2 = [3,2,1,5,4]
>>> for i in l1:
...    if i not in l2:
...      print('doh')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for individual items in the `list_one`.

```
count=0
for i in list_one:
    if i in list_two:
        count += 1

    if count==len(list_one):
        print("All items covered!")
```