# Why can't you use 'in' to test if a one list is a subset of another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am reading through *Learning Python* and just finished the section on lists. While I was playing around to see what I can do with them, I came across something odd:

```
[2, 3] in [1, 2, 3, 4] == False
```

You can't test for subsets of lists using the `in` keyword. Why is this the case?

Comment: You can put lists in lists. `[2,3] in [1,[2,3],4]` is True

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/python-verifying-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-the-other

Comment: @NightShadeQueen, Not quite the same. The op in that question is looking for a way to check for subset. I'm asking why `in` isn't working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
[2,3] `is not in` [1,2,3,4]

[2,3] `is in` [1, [2,3] ,4]
```

2 and 3 are elements in the list but the list [2,3] is not an element in the list.

Answer (score 6):

That is because `[2, 3]` is in fact **not** in `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

To test for subsets, use the `issubset` function in the `sets` module.

```
a = [2, 3]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4]

set(a).issubset(set(b))
```

Comment: Note: `issubset()` is only one possible interpretation. `substr in text` (order, duplicates) is another interpretation e.g., `'bc' in 'abc'`; and `subseq in seq` (order, duplicates are preserved but gaps are possible) e.g., `aad` in `abacd` but `aad` not in `ad`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfect use of the `set` object, which contains a `issubset` method for this exact purpose:

```
set([2, 3]).issubset([1, 2, 3, 4]) # test if 2 and 3 are located in another iterable
```

Answer (score 3):

It's because `in` checks for element equality. If you had something like

```
[2, 3] in [[1,2], [2, 3], [3, 4]]
```

it would work. This works because `in` looks through the list, compares your element to each of the elements in the list it's looking through, and if any of the comparisons is `True`, the `in` statement is `True.`

You're basically asking why this doesn't return true:

```
for x in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
    if x == [1,2]:
         return True
```

Comment: It all makes perfect sense in hindsight :)

Answer (score 2):

in is for testing list membership, for example, `1 in [1,2,3]` is `True`.
If you intend to check subset (order and repetition doesn't matter), you can use the subset operator (looks like less-than-or-equals): `{1,2} <= {1,2,3,4,5}`

Answer (score 1):

This is because 'in' checks if any of the items in the list match your given item.

The items in the list are 1, 2, 3, and 4.

Your item is the list [2, 3], which does not equal any of the above.

Answer (score 1):

That's because in both lists, the items are of type **int** not **list**.

```
[1,2,3,4,5] does not include an item of type list i.e [2,3]. Although 2 and 3
are items in [1,2,3,4,5]

[2,3]  in [1, [2,3] ,4] returns true because [2,3] is in [1,[2,3],4,5]
```

You'll have to test the membership of 2 or 3 in [1,2,3,4,5] separately to return **True**

```
 i.e: 2 in [1,2,3,4,5] or 3 in [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: Another option is to convert the lists to sets and use {2,3}.issubset{1,2,3,4,5}