# How to check if Iterable_1 in iterable_2

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

How to check if, lets say, list_1 **in** list_2 without iterating the list_1? Are there any specific 'pythonic' ways or it's better to stick to:

```
for i in list_1:
  if i in list_2:
```

Thank you!

Comment: I can think of at least 5 possible meanings of "list_1 in list_2". Would you care to share yours?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/python-verifying-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-the-other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be interested in cases where every element in list_1 is also in list_2. In that case a simple

```
set(list_1) <= set(list_2)
```

works.

Of course -- if list_2 is a list of lists and you want to know if list_1 is one of those lists a simple

```
list_1 in list_2
```

works.

Alternatively, you could be asking if list_1 is a *slice* of list_2. Just check

```
list_1 in (list_2[i:j] for j in range(len(list_2)+1) for i in range(j))
```

You could also check is list_1 is a sub-multiset of list_2 or if list_1 is an increasing subsequence of list_2. I'll leave those as exercises.

Comment: Thanks! That is exatly what I tried to learn.
I also tried a "subset" exercise, please let me know if there is a better way:
    subset_of = True
    while list_1:
        try:
            list_2.remove(list_1.pop())
        except ValueError:
            subset_of = False
            break

    print(subset_of)

Comment: Sorry, could not figure out how to format code in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Python has some functional support with map and filter which help in avoiding levels of iteration.

For iteration with inner conditions/early returns, the any and all functions are effective.

Also, set operations (intersect, union, difference) can be helpful too. It's probably what I would choose when just seeing if the elements in list 1 are in list 2.

```
list_1 = [ 2, 3 ]
list_2 = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]

print set(list_1) in set(list_2) # True

# a more functional approach, although really only makes sense for more specific complex examples!
import operator,itertools,functools
is_in_list_2 = functools.partial(operator.contains,list_2)
print all(itertools.imap(is_in_list_2,list_1)) # will hopefully not call contains more than it needs to!
```