# Check if all elements in list1 exist in list2 python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, subset

I want to be able to find whether all elements in list1 exist in list2, both lists containing chars. The number of times the same element appears in each list is important.

I tried using subsets however that didn't take note of the number of times an item appeared in a list

e.g.

```
list1 = [a, b, c]
list2 = [a, b, c, b]
```

It would find list2 a subset of list1, whereas I would only want my function to execute if:

```
list1 = [a, b, c, b, i]
list2 = [a, c, b, b]
```

as this means **all** items in list2 appear in list1.

If anyone was interested, using a counter was inefficient for large strings so I ended up adding all elements of list1 to a dictionary, with the values being number of occurances of each element and subtracted all elements of list2. If any values ended up negative not all items in list2 appear in list1

Comment: Get the count in both lists and then check if the count of all items in `list2` is exactly same in `list1`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: This is very unclear, please give a better example of input/output

Comment: And this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/16579133/2141635

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could count the items in both lists with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and check that the counts for the corresponding items in the first list are >= than those in the second:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter("abcbi")
>>> d = Counter("acbb")
>>> c.subtract(d)
>>> if all(v >= 0 for k, v in c.items()):
...     print("All items exist")
... 
All items exist
```

Comment: This is very nice, I didn't know of `subtract` before! I think we have a winner.

Comment: This works however is very inefficient if the counters have large strings

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b']    
c1 = Counter(list1)
c2 = Counter(list2)

for key, count in c1.iteritems():
    if c2[key] < count:
        break
else:
    print 'list2 has all the chracters in list1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`issuperset`](http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/sets/issuperset.html):

```
>>> list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'i']
>>> list2 = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'b']
>>> set(list1).issuperset(set(list2)) # all items of list2 exist in list1
True
>>> set(list2).issuperset(set(list1)) # all items of list1 does not exist in list 2
False
```

Comment: *I tried using subsets however that didn't take note of the **number of times** an item appeared in a list*

Comment: From the question statement, this seems *to me* as the correct answer

Comment: This does nothing different from what I can see. It doesn't acknowledge item frequency in the lists

Comment: Again, from what you state in your question this is what you "want". If you would be more clear we could give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem, you'll need to

1. Verify that all elements in `list2` appear in `list1` but
2. No element in `list2` appears more often than it does in `list2`

This can be done quite easily using `collections.Counter`:

```
import collections

def f(list1, list2):
    d1 = collections.Counter(list1)
    d2 = collections.Counter(list2)
    return set(d1.keys()).issuperset(set(d2.keys())) \
       and all(d2[k] <= d1[k] for k in d1.keys())
```

This first checks (using `set.issuperset`) that all the different elements of `list2` are contained in `list1`. If that's true, it checks how often each element occurs in `list2` and verifies that it appears less often (or equally often) in `list1`.

Comment: This is a more verbose version of what "eugene y" wrote, if possible I'd rather go with his version than mine.