# python test multiple conditions with or operator

Tags: python

How can I test if one of the multiple items exist in a list using or?

I tried:

```
data = [[1,'a',4,],['a','b','c'],['c',3,5]...]
for i,val enumerate(data):
    if 'a' or 'b' or 'c' in val:
        data.pop(i)
```

But it removes the first row only

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/python-verifying-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-the-other is probably a better duplicate.

Comment: how is this a duplicate?

Comment: The question that ayhan gave as a duplicate is exactly your problem and shows how to solve it directly. The one I linked provides a better solution without using the `or` operator.

Comment: The mistake in `x or y or z == 0` is the same as the mistake in `'a' or 'b' or 'c' in val`, so yeah, this is a duplicate. Read through the answers and you'll see why.

Comment: Somehow everyday there are at least two people who ask the very same question :(

Answer (score 0):

You must test the conditions one at a time:

```
if 'a' in val or 'b' in val or 'c' in val:
```

Alternatively, you create two lists, convert them to sets, and test if the first list is a subset of another list. See [Python - verifying if one list is a subset of the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/python-verifying-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-the-other) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if val in ['a','b','c']:
```