# Insert a user input into a list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nltk, user-input

I am working with NLTK and I would like to find all sentences that include a given set of key words. For example, it is currently `[x for x in tokenized_sent if 'key_word1' and 'key_word2' and 'key_word3' in x]`. I would like to set it up so that a user can input any number of words that can then be set equal to these key words separated by `and`.

I have tried something like inserting `user_input_list = ['key_word1','key_word2']` by writing `[x for x in tokenized_sent if user_input_list[0] and user_input_list[1] in x]` which works but there has got to be a better way, especially a way to handle any given number of words to look for. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does \`a == b or c or d\` always evaluate to True?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-b-or-c-or-d-always-evaluate-to-true)

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize [set subsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/how-can-i-verify-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-another). Make the user input list a set and see if it is a subset of your key words.

```
[x for x in tokenized_sent if set(user_input_list).issubset(x)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could use the *all*-Keyword:

```py
[words for words in tokenized_sent if all([keyword in words for keyword in keywords])]
```

Spend attention: The first in results *in*-Statement a boolean while the second one is used to get elements from the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter` and `all` methods:

```
list(filter(lambda x: all(key in x for key in user_input_list), tokenized_sent))
```