# Optimal check if the elements of a list are in another list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, hashtable

I need to check if the items in one list are in another list. Both lists contain paths to files.

```
    list1 = [a/b/c/file1.txt, b/c/d/file2.txt]
    list2 = [a/b/c/file1.txt, b/c/d/file2.txt, d/f/g/test4.txt, d/k/test5.txt]
```

I tried something like:

```
    len1 = len(list1)
    len2 = len(list2)

    res = list(set(list2) - set(list1))
    len3 = len(res)

    if len2 - len1 == len3:
        print("List2 contains all the items in list1")
```

But it's not an optimal option, I have lists of 50k+ items. I think a good solution can be by creating a hash table, but I don't know exactly how I could build it. If you have any suggestions you can leave a message.

Comment: What's the question here? Why do sets seem suboptimal to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `set`s are based on hashing, hence you cannot put unhashable objects inside `set`s.
Rather calculating lengths, directly perform `set difference`:

```
>>> list1 = ['a/b/c/file1.txt', 'b/c/d/file2.txt']
>>> list2 = ['a/b/c/file1.txt', 'b/c/d/file2.txt', 'd/f/g/test4.txt', 'd/k/test5.txt']
>>> if (set(list1) - set(list2)):  # will return empty set (Falsy) if all are contained
        print("List2 contains all the items in list1")

List2 contains all the items in list1
```

Here is the breakdown:

```
>>> difference = set(list1) - set(list2)
>>> difference
set()
>>> bool(difference)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

> I think a good solution can be by creating a hash table, but I don't know exactly how I could build it.

Sets are already implemented [using hash tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-set-implemented), so you are already doing that.

Supposing you don't have (or don't care about) duplicates, you could try:

```py
list1 = [1,2,3]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]
set(list1).issubset(list2)
```

Notice how there's no need to convert `list2` to a set, see the comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27116142/6843675).

EDIT: both your solution and mine are O(n) average, it won't get faster than that. But your solution could avoid some operations like converting the difference `res` into a list just to get its size.

Comment: What if I need to know the items that are not on the other list?

Comment: Then you can use `set(list2).difference(list1)`, it will return a set with everything that is in `list2` but not in `list1`.