# Combine list that shares common value from two dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Let's say you have two data frame columns that have some list:

[image]

What will the code in python looks like?

Comment: What is the logic which leads to the last df? Why do we have two rows?

Comment: @aprospero the first row is for where the id that have list that share common element and the column two is what the element that share common element

Answer (score 1):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Id':[1,2,3],
        'a':[[1,2,3],[4, 5],[6]]
    }, 
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Id':[1,2,3],
        'b':[[3],[6, 7],[8]]
    }, 
)


df3 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'Id': [
            [int(df1[pd.Series(map(tuple, df1['a']))  == tuple(i)].index.values)+1, 
             int(df1[pd.Series(map(tuple, df2['b']))  == tuple(j)].index.values)+1] 
            for j in df2['b'] for i in df1['a'] if set.intersection(set(i), set(j))],
        'a&b': [list(set.union(set(i), set(j))) 
                for j in df2['b'] 
                for i in df1['a'] 
                if set.intersection(set(i), set(j))],
    }
)
```

**:OUPTUT:**
[image]

I know my solution is very messy but when I try to solve to in other way like without use of tuple compression which one is very easy then I got various kind of error like `ValueError: Lengths must match to compare` which is common we all know about this type of

Comment: `(df1['a']))  == i).index.values` logic is better then `int(df1[pd.Series(map(tuple, df1['a']))  == tuple(i)`  but first one cause lots of error and bugs

Comment: it says 'Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match)'. I want to do it in dataframe that has different length.

Answer (score 0):

- start with a Cartesian product between **df** and **df1**
- next find rows where **b** is a subset of **a** [subset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/how-can-i-verify-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-another)
- use `set.union()` to get superset of **a** and **b**
- build `list` of combined **id** columns
- a bit of cleanup - `dropna()` and just columns you want `loc[]`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3],
             "a":[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6]]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3],
             "b":[[3],[6,7],[8]]})

df2 = (df.assign(foo=1)
 .merge(df1.assign(foo=1), on="foo")
 .assign(**{"a&b":lambda dfa: np.where(dfa.apply(lambda r: any(x in r.a for x in r.b), axis=1),
                                     dfa.apply(lambda r: list(set(r.a).union(r.b)), axis=1),
                                     np.nan)})
 .dropna()
 .assign(id=lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,["id_x","id_y"]].apply(list, axis=1))
 .loc[:,["id","a&b"]]
)
```

|  | id | a&b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | [1, 1] | [1, 2, 3] |
| 7 | [3, 2] | [6, 7] |

#### alternate approach

- this eliminates the combination explosion of a Cartesian product
- copy the `list` before it's exploded so it can be easily reconstructed

```
(df.assign(a_arr=df.a).explode("a")
 .merge(df1.assign(b_arr=df1.b).explode("b"), left_on="a", right_on="b")
 .assign(**{"id":lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,["id_x","id_y"]].apply(list, axis=1),
           "a&b":lambda dfa: dfa.loc[:,["a_arr","b_arr"]].apply(lambda r: list(set(r.a_arr).union(r.b_arr)), axis=1)})
 .loc[:,["id","a&b"]]
)
```

Comment: It say 'Unable to allocate 26.2 GiB for an array with shape (3513454770,) and data type int64'. What happened?

Comment: it's the Cartesian product - it will generate `len(df) * len(df1)` rows.  is there anything in your DFs that allows way to reduce number of possible combinations to be reduced?

Comment: I've updated with an alternate approach that does not do a Cartesian product.  combinations will depend on size of lists