# I need speed. Comparing two very large dictionaries: key are indexes original pandas index stored as tuples, values are lists of strings

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, compare, nested-loops

Firstly thank you for the thousand answered questions from others I have read and used. but now I need to post my own question. Out of 4000 lines of well working code, the following 6 lines were taking weeks and now take days but I still need this to run way faster. My chunk of particularly SLOW code:

```
    for i in PepCombDict.items():
        for x in PepSeqDictFull_NoneUnique_NRP.items():
            if x[0] == i[0][0] or x[0] == i[0][1]:
                continue
            elif(set(x[1]).issubset(set(i[1]))):
                subsumablelist.append([i[0][0],i[0][1],x[0]])
```

`PepCombDict` is a dictionary with first entry as follows:
key  is a pair of values: (0, 1)
value is list:

```
['TVMENFVAFVDK', 'KVPQVSTPTLVEVSR', 'DTHKSEIAHR', 'YICDNQDTISSK', 'KQTALVELLK', 'FKDLGEEHFK', 'EYEATLEECCAK', 'AEFVEVTK', 'LVNELTEFAK', 'LVTDLTK', 'LGEYGFQNALIVR', 'LSQKFPK', 'HLVDEPQNLIK', 'YLYEIAR', 'SIVHPSYNSNTLNNDIMLIK', 'SAYPGQITSNMFCAGYLEGGK', 'LKSAASLNSR', 'SAASLNSR', 'SGIQVR', 'NKPGVYTK', 'LGEDNINVVEGNEQFISASK', 'SSGTSYPDVLK', 'APILSDSSCKSAYPGQITSNMFCAGYLEGGK', 'SIVHPSYNSNTLNNDIMLIKLK']
```

Similarly, `PepSeqDictFull_NoneUnique_NRP` is also a dictionary with first entry as follows:
Key is a single value: 9
Value is: list

```
['VTMQNLNDR', 'QSVEADINGLR', 'QSVEADINGLRR', 'LAADDFR', 'DYSKYYK', 'SKELTTEIDNNIEQISSYK', 'KDAEAWFNEK', 'ISSSKGSLGGGFSSGGFSGGSFSR', .....
```

The objective of this code block is to find all cases where the list of string sequences found in `PepSeqDictFull_NoneUnique_NRP` is a subset of the string sequences found in `PepCombDict`; and when found, save the keys (indexes) as a list of three numbers (combination of the two keys).

If someone knows how to make this go way faster, I would greatly appreciate it. I am totally open to changing formats of any part. I learned python with this pandemic and want to stick with python. `PepSeqDictFull_NoneUnique_NRP` is always smaller. `PepCombDict` can range in size from 2,000,000 to 100,000,000.

`if x[0] == i[0][0] or x[0] == i[0][1]: continue`
is just there to prevent an entry being found to be a subset of itself.

Best,

Tom

Comment: One obvious improvement is to move `set(i[1])` out of the inner loop.  There's no reason to keep creating it over and over in your inner loop.  Instead, create it in your outer loop, then reuse it in the inner loop.

Comment: This link gives a pretty good discussion of different techniques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/how-can-i-verify-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
combs = {
    (0, 1): ['TVMENFVAFVDK', 'KVPQVSTPTLVEVSR', 'DTHKSEIAHR', 'YICDNQDTISSK', 'KQTALVELLK', 'FKDLGEEHFK', 'EYEATLEECCAK', 'AEFVEVTK', 'LVNELTEFAK', 'LVTDLTK', 'LGEYGFQNALIVR', 'LSQKFPK', 'HLVDEPQNLIK', 'YLYEIAR', 'SIVHPSYNSNTLNNDIMLIK', 'SAYPGQITSNMFCAGYLEGGK', 'LKSAASLNSR', 'SAASLNSR', 'SGIQVR', 'NKPGVYTK', 'LGEDNINVVEGNEQFISASK', 'SSGTSYPDVLK', 'APILSDSSCKSAYPGQITSNMFCAGYLEGGK', 'SIVHPSYNSNTLNNDIMLIKLK']
}

seqs = {
    9: ['VTMQNLNDR', 'QSVEADINGLR', 'QSVEADINGLRR', 'LAADDFR', 'DYSKYYK', 'SKELTTEIDNNIEQISSYK', 'KDAEAWFNEK', 'ISSSKGSLGGGFSSGGFSGGSFSR']
}
```

[As @TomKarzes noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68148231/i-need-speed-comparing-two-very-large-dictionaries-key-are-indexes-original-pa#comment120445429_68148231), you can create the sets outside the loop:

```py
combs = {k: set(v) for k, v in combs.items()}
seqs = {k: set(v) for k, v in seqs.items()}
```

You can also make a list comprehension while building `subsumablelist`:

```py
subsumablelist = [
    [comb_ids[0], comb_ids[1], seq_id]
    for comb_ids, comb in combs.items()
    for seq_id, seq in seqs.items()
    if (seq_id not in comb_ids) and all(subseq in comb for subseq in seq)
]
```

Using `timeit`, the time improvement from your code (4.97s) to the proposed code (3.03s) is 39%.

---

Using `seq.issubset(comb)` instead of `all(subseq in comb for subseq in seq)` (2.79s) increases the time improvement to 43%.