# How to check combination of elements present in a list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list and It is easy to find if an element is present in a list or not but how to find if a combination of two or all the elements are present in a list?

```
listi = ["head","strong","pain","chores"]
```

for one element:

```
if i in listi:
    print("available")
else:
    print("Not available")
```

But How to check combination of elements like if `head,strong` is present in a list or `pain,cores,strong` or any conbimation of elements is present in a list? How to do?

I understand that we can do via subsets but in that case, I have to create subset of every combination which is not possible

Comment: ``if "head" in listi and "strong" in listi:``? Do you care about duplicates, e.g. is `"head","head"` present in the list if there is only one `"head"`?

Comment: An easier one: ```if "head" and "strong" in listi:
    print("Available")```

Comment: @SanskarSingh And a wrong one. Try ``if "head" and "strong" in ["strong"]: print(True)``.

Comment: This is also answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/how-can-i-verify-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-another

Comment: No it is answered partially. but in my case, I have to create a subset fof every combination which is not possible

Comment: "I have to create a subset fof every combination which is not possible" Why not? How do you know which combinations to check for if you cannot create them?

Comment: "I have to create a subset of every combination" -- every combination *of what*? Is there another "main" list which has all the possible values?

Answer (score 3):

You might use `set` arithmetic for this task as follows:

```
listi = ["head","strong","pain","chores"]
required = set(["pain","chores","strong"])
print(required.issubset(listi))
```

output

```
True
```

If you want know more about, read [Sets in docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

Comment: Thanks but In this approach then I have to create a required variable for every combination which is not possible like for pain.,chores it is one variable and then chores,head another one. not possible

Comment: @Enigmaderockz How do you know which combinations to check for if you cannot create them? Note that there is no need to store them into variables, e.g. ``set(["pain","chores","strong"]).issubset(listi)`` works (as do many other variations).

Comment: FWIW, ``set(["pain","chores","strong"])`` should just be ``{"pain","chores","strong"}``.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and a comprehension:

```
listi = ["head","strong","pain","chores"]
try1 = ["head", "strong"]
try2 = ["head", "face"]

all(e in listi for e in try1)  ## True
all(e in listi for e in try2)  ## False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [any / all](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/any-all-in-python/) methods:

```
if all([word_to_check in listi for word_to_check in words])
```

Comment: Heads up that the list created by the ``[`` ``]`` is not needed. Omitting the ``[`` ``]`` turns this into a memory efficient generator.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sets:

```
list_ = ["head","strong","pain","chores"]
sublist = ["head", "strong"]

intersect = set(list_) & set(sublist)

if intersect:
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks but In this approach then I have to create a sublist for every combination which is not possible like for pain.,chores it is one variable and then chores,head another one. not possible

Comment: it's not necessary you can have a list of all sublists, and then you for statement.

for example


sublists = [["head", "strong"], [strong","pain","chores"]]
list_as_set = set(list_)

all_has_intersect = all(list_as_set & set(sublist) for sublist in sublists)