# Check that elements exist within a list Python

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to check that Elements within list1 are part of list2?
What I've tried is down below... But I don't get an ouput. I'm guessing the 'in' function only deals with individual elements?

```
pattern=['Tacos', 'Pizza']
Foods=['Tacos', 'Pizza', 'Burgers', 'Fries', 'Ice-cream']

if pattern in foods:
    print('yes')
```

Comment: It's not clear from your post what exactly you want to achieve. Do you want to test if *any* of the strings is contained in `foods`, or *all* of them? And if all, do they have to be consecutive? Or just in that order? Or can they be in any order?

Comment: Given the accepted answer, this seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/how-can-i-verify-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it as a simple set logic.

```py
set(pattern).issubset(foods)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `pattern` is a list but you want to check every element inside the pattern list then you need to use a loop.

```py
pattern=['Tacos', 'Pizza']
Foods=['Tacos', 'Pizza', 'Burgers', 'Fries', 'Ice-cream']

for patt in pattern:
    if patt in foods:
        print('yes')
```

Answer (score 0):

Substract foods from pattern and the list should be empty.

```
len( set(pattern) - set(Foods) ) == 0
```

or, intersection should be equal to the length of the pattern

```
len( set(pattern) & set(Foods) ) == len(pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `set` logic:

```
>>> set(pattern).issubset(foods)
True
```

Using iteration over the lists (this is less efficient in general, especially if `pattern` is long, but it's useful to understand how this works where your original `in` check didn't):

```
>>> all(food in foods for food in pattern)
True
```