# Assert list B contains list A

Tags: python, python-unittest

I want to assert two list in Python:

```
list_a = [1, 2, 3]
list_b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]


assert contains(list_a, list_b)  # not working
assert list_a in list_b  # not working
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I verify if one list is a subset of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/how-can-i-verify-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-another)

Comment: Define "contains".

Comment: As Kelly said, your question is unclear. What result do you expect if list A's elements are all present in list B but not in the same order? What about if all of list A's elements are in list B, but list A has some elements with more duplicates than list B? Also, please don't just say "not working" but define what "not working" means.

Answer (score -1):

If the order matter you can follow [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/r4tkf6/how_to_check_is_a_sequence_of_given_numbers/) recipe

In alternative, you should use [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
# Is list_a a subset of list_b ?
not (set(list_a)-set(list_b))
```