# Python function to check if a json file is a subset of an other json file doesn't work if there is a list nested inside the json file

Tags: python

First I convert the json to a dict and then I want to check if one is a subset of the other in a nested way. an example of file I want to check is the one below:
you can consider the following JSON data as set A, delete one item and cnosider it subset B

```
'''
 {
    "scheduleType": null,
    "scheduleOption": null,
    "timezone": null,
    "workflowHiveOnly": null,
    "hiveEngineVersion": null,
    "hivePoolName": null,
    "prestoPoolName": null,
    "maxActivationBehaviorRow": null,
    "allowActivationBehavior": null,
    "master": {
      "parentTableName": "null"
    },
    "attributes": [],
    "behaviors": [
      {
        "name": null,
        "parentTableName": null,
        "parentKey": null,
        "foreignKey": null,
        "matrixTableName": null,
        "allColumns": null,
        "defaultTimeFilterEnabled": null,
        "schema": [
          {
            "name": null,
            "type": null,
            "parentColumn:null,
            "matrixColumnName": null
          },
          {
            "name":null,
            "type":null,
            "parentColumn": null,
            "matrixColumnName":null
          } ,
 {

   "name": null,
   "parentTableName": null,
   "parentKey": null,
   "foreignKey": null,
   "matrixTableName": null,
   "allColumns": null,
   "defaultTimeFilterEnabled": null,
   "schema": []
 },
 {

   "name": null,
   "parentTableName": null,
   "parentKey": null,
   "foreignKey": null,
   "matrixTableName": null,
   "allColumns": null,
   "defaultTimeFilterEnabled": null,
   "schema": [
     {
       "name": null,
       "type": null,
       "parentColumn": null,
       "matrixColumnName": null
     }
'''
def is_subset(a,b):
    def recursive_check_subset(a,b):
        for x in a:
            if not isinstance(a[x],dict):
                yield (x in b ) and (a[x] == b[x]) #return a bool
            else:
                if x in b:
                    yield all(recursive_check_subset(a[x],b[x]))
                else:
                    yield False
    return all(recursive_check_subset(a,b))
```

The code function well when I have a dictionary inside of dictionaries. But I stops working as soon as we get to a list.

I excpted this function to recursively check the dictionary inside of it and see if the elements in there are a subset of the others.

for example if I have 3 values in dictionary A and 4 values in dictionary B. I only want True if the 3 keys in dictionary A have the same values in dictionary B. And this should happen recursively for each element of the lists and for each key. In the actual data I use inside the lists there are other dictionary and there can be list inside those dictionaries as well

Comment: What do you want to do when there is a list? Shall both list be identical or shall the first be a true sublist of the first, or be a subset in same order, or ...?

Comment: if you given an example of a JSON file given a valid JSON file

Answer (score 0):

The following logic checks whether dict `d2` is a subset of dict `d1` or not. It recursively calls `is_subset` function if `d1[k]` for some subset key, `k` is a dict. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16579085/how-can-i-verify-if-one-list-is-a-subset-of-another), we can check if a list is a subset of another.

This has some assumptions:

- if `d1[k]` is a dict, then `d2[k]` is also a dict, for a subset key `k`.
- if `d1[k]` is a list, its items are not further dicts/iterables that need to be checked.

```py
def is_subset(d1: dict, d2: dict) -> bool:
    for k in d2:
        if k not in d1:
            return False

        if isinstance(d1[k], dict):
            if not is_subset(d1[k], d2[k]):
                return False
        elif isinstance(d1[k], list):
            if not set(d2[k]).issubset(d1[k]):
                return False
        else:
            if d1[k] != d2[k]:
                return False
    return True
```

If you also want strings to be subsets too, then modify the line:

`elif isinstance(d1[k], list):`

to:

`elif isinstance(d1[k], list | str):`

Hope this helps!

Comment: unfortunately I receive this error "if not set(d2[k]).issubset(d1[k])    TypeError: unashable type: dict"

Comment: I think the problem is that, inside of each element of the list there is a dictionary that should be checked if it's element are a subset. and inside the those element there could be an array

Comment: If you can provide a minimal reproducible JSON example, it will be helpful to write custom code for the use case.

Comment: I updated the example data